# Error : Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, mvc, poo

Estoy haciendo un crud con `MVC` y `POO` siguiendo un curso y me aparece el siguiente error

[image: ERROR]
LLevo un rato tratando de resolver el problema pero no encuentro forma, este es el archivo donde me marca el error

```
    class EntidadBase{

            private $table;
            private $db;
            private $conectar;

            public function __contruct($table){

                $this->table = (string) $table;

                require_once 'Conectar.php';
                $this->conectar = new Conectar();
                $this->db = $this->conectar->Conexion();

            }

            public function getConectar(){      // Para sacar la conexion desde otros sitios solo llamandolo

                return $this->conectar;

            }

            public function db(){

                return $this->db;

            }

            public function getAll(){           

                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table ORDER BY id DESC"); // Linea que marca el error

                while($row = $query->fetch_object()){

                    $resultSet[] = $row;

                }

                return $resultSet;

            }

            public function getById($id){       // Consulta a un id especifico en la tabla

                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE id=$id");

                if($row = $query->fetch_object()){

                    $resultSet = $row;

                }

                return $resultSet;

            }

            public function getBy($column, $value){         // Consulta a una columna especifica con su valor especifico

                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE $column='$value'");

                while($row = $query->fetch_object()){

                    $resultSet[] = $row;

                }

                return $resultSet;

            }

            public function deleteById($id){            // Eliminar un elemento

                $query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE id = $id");
                return $query;

            }

            public function deleteBy($column, $value){

                $query = $this->bd->query("DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE $column = '$value'");
                return $query;

            }

        }

Si alguien podría guiarme, apenas estoy empezando a aprender la `POO`.
```

Codigo de UsuariosController

```
class UsuariosController extends ControladorBase{

        public function __construct(){

            parent::__construct();

        }

        public function index(){

            $usuario = new Usuario();

            $allUsers = $usuario->getAll();

            $this->view("index", array(
                "allUsers" => $allUsers,
                "Hola"     => "Ejemplo de MVC"
            ));

        }

        public function crear(){

            if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){

                $usuario = new Usuario();

                $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $password = sha1($_POST['password']);

                $usuario->setNombre($nombre);
                $usuario->setApellido($apellido);
                $usuario->setEmail($email);
                $usuario->setPassword($password);

                $save = $usuario->save();

            }

            $this->redirect('Usuarios', 'index');

        }

        public function borrar(){

            if(isset($_GET['id'])){

                $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

                $usuario = new Usuario();
                $usuario->deleteById($id);

                $this->redirect();

            }

        }

    }
```

Codigo Usuarios.php

```
class Usuario extends EntidadBase{

        private $id;
        private $nombre;
        private $apellido;
        private $email;
        private $password;

        public function __construct($table){

            $table = "usuarios";
            parent::__construct($table);

        }

        public function getId() {

            return $this->id;

        }

        public function setId($id) {

            $this->id = $id;

        }

        public function getNombre() {

            return $this->nombre;

        }

        public function setNombre($nombre) {

            $this->nombre = $nombre;

        }

        public function getApellido() {

            return $this->apellido;

        }

        public function setApellido($apellido) {

            $this->apellido = $apellido;

        }

        public function getEmail() {

            return $this->email;

        }

        public function setEmail($email) {

            $this->email = $email;

        }

        public function getPassword() {

            return $this->password;

        }

        public function setPassword($password) {

            $this->password = $password;

        }

        public function save(){

            $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(id, nombre, apellido, email, password) 
                    VALUES (NULL,
                    '". $this->nombre ."',
                    '". $this->apellido ."',
                    '". $this->email ."',
                    '". $this->password ."')";

                    $save = $this->db()->query($query);

            return $save;

        }

    }
```

Comment: No funciona, el error continua ademas de aparecer otro

Comment: Edwin tienes un lío de conexiones que no se entiende nada. Parece que al final no se está conectado a la BD. Todo esto es demasiado confuso: `require_once 'Conectar.php';
            $this->conectar = new Conectar();
            $this->db = $this->conectar->Conexion();`  y encima, también tienes un método `getConectar()` y otro método `db()` ... Es necesario que te aclares con tantas conexiones que al final parece que ninguna conecta.

Comment: ¿Como lo puedo arreglar?, ya que el codigo es de un ejemplo que estoy siguiendo porque apenas estoy aprendiendo a usar la `poo`, porque el metodo `Conexion()`, si conecta correctamente porque eso ya lo comprobe

Comment: ¿Esta línea qué es lo que hace exactamente:  `$this->db = $this->conectar->Conexion();`? A mi me parece que esta clase `EntidadBase` sobra. Yo tendría una clase que sea la encargada de manejar las conexiones, y le mandaría a ella las consultas. No veo por qué tienes que tener una clase solamente para pasarle en parámetro el nombre de tabla o de las columnas. O sea, una clase debe ser para algo más... [Mira aquí por ejemplo](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO). En esta clase se envían las consultas a la clase que maneja las conexiones directamente. Cualquier consulta.

Comment: `$this->db = $this->conectar->Conexion();`, por lo que entiendo lo que hace es almacenar la conexion para usarla

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código de UsuariosController.php?

Comment: @ErnestoRM, ya lo puse

Comment: ¿Podrías poner ahora de dónde sale la clase `Usuario`? @EdwinAquino

Comment: @ernestoRM, listo

Answer (score 0):

Hola Edwin espero que esté muy bien, verá, como estamos trabajando con el patrón MVC y la POO debemos recordar la modularidad, es decir, debemos dividir nuestra aplicación en partes más pequeñas para que el desarrollo y depuración se realice de manera más fácil. Lo que le recomiendo es lo siguiente:

1. No realice instancias en el modelo, hágalo en el controlador. Véalo de esta forma: El modelo es una idea de lo que se quiere hacer, por ejemplo: una casa, aquí es donde plasmamos la idea, ahora, en el controlador es donde instanciamos y por lo tanto creamos nuestro objeto o en su defecto nuestra casa, si instanciamos dentro del modelo sería como crear nuestra casa y meterla en nuestra cabeza en forma de idea, raro ¿cierto?
2. En su archivo llamado 'conectar.php' puede hacer lo siguiente:

> ```
> abstract class Conexion extends PDO{
>   private $respuestaConexion = false; //variable encargada de determinar el estado  de la conexion
>   private $dbname = "xxx"; //el nombre de su base de datos
>   private $host = "localhost"; //host
>   private $port = 5432; //puerto
>   private $user = "xxxx"; //usuario
>   private $password = "xxxx"; //clave
>   private $options = [
>       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION //reportes de excepciones
>   ];
> ```

```
    protected function realizandoConexion(){
        try{
            parent::__construct("pgsql:dbname={$this->dbname};host={$this->host};port={$this->port}",$this->user,$this->password,$this->options);
            $this->respuestaConexion = true;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->respuestaConexion = false;
        }
    }

    protected function getStatusConexion(){
        return $this->respuestaConexion;
    }

    protected function cerrarConexion(){
        $this->respuestaConexion = false;
    }

}
```

Lo que hacemos es crear una clase abstracta de esta manera tendremos una capa de abstracción que PDO no nos brinda a la hora de utilizar bases de datos y también nos sirve para utilizar esta clase dentro del modelo sin instanciar, veamos como quedaría tu código hermano:

Modelo:

```
require_once 'Conectar.php';

class EntidadBase extends Conexion{ //Heredamos atributos y metodos de la clase 'Conexion' para usarlos en nuestra clase 'EntidadBase'

    private $table;

    public function __contruct($table){

        $this->table = (string) $table;
        Conexion::realizandoConexion(); //Utilizamos el metodo llamado 'relizandoConexion' perteneciente a la clase 'Conexion' definida en nuestro archivo 'Conexion.php' 
        if(Conexion::getStatusConexion() == true){//Verificamos el estado de la conexion
            return "Conexion Establecida.";
        }else{
            return "Conexion Fallida.";
        }
    }

    public function getAll(){           

        $query = Conexion::prepare("SELECT * FROM :table ORDER BY id DESC"); // Linea que marca el error
        $query -> bindParam(':table',$this->table,PDO::PARAM_STR); //Relacionamos el parametro de entrada '$this->table' al nombre de la variable ':table'
        $query -> execute(); //ejecutamos consulta
        return $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //la variable '$query' retornará los registros especificados en la consulta SQL, esto lo usaremos en el controlador gracias a la palabra reservada 'return'

        //A PARTIR DE AQUI PUEDES SEGUIR EL MISMO EJEMPLO
        //Reemplazarás $this->db por Conexion::
        //Utiliza 'binParam' al momento de realizar la consulta ya que tienes parametros de entrada
        //Todos esos 'while' te recomiendo cambiarlos por 'foreach' y usarlos en la vista, más abajo te daré un ejemplo

    }

    public function getById($id){       // Consulta a un id especifico en la tabla

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE id=$id");

        if($row = $query->fetch_object()){

            $resultSet = $row;

        }

        return $resultSet;

    }

    public function getBy($column, $value){         // Consulta a una columna especifica con su valor especifico

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE $column='$value'");

        while($row = $query->fetch_object()){

            $resultSet[] = $row;

        }

        return $resultSet;

    }

    public function deleteById($id){            // Eliminar un elemento

        $query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE id = $id");
        return $query;

    }

    public function deleteBy($column, $value){

        $query = $this->bd->query("DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE $column = '$value'");
        return $query;

    }

}
```

Controlador:

```
<?php    
    require_once 'modelo.php'; //Incluimos el archivo que tenemos en la conexion
    $EntidadBase = new EntidadBase(); //Instaciamos 
    $datosEB = $EntidadBase -> getAll(); //El metodo getAll() retorna los registros de tu tabla, esos registros se guardarán en $datosEB
    require_once 'vista.php';
?>
```

Vista:

```
foreach($datosEB as $var){
    //AQUI VAN LAS FILAS QUE QUIERES QUE SE IMPRIMAN, POR EJEMPLO, OJO, SOLO ES UN EJEMPLOO, USTED LO HARA CON CADA UNA DE SUS COLUMNAS EN LAS CUALES QUIERE QUE SE IMPRIMAN DATOS
     echo "<tr>"; 

        echo "<td class='text-center'>{$var["id"]}</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>{$var["nombre_triun"]}</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>{$var["apellido_triun"]}</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>{$var["cedula_triun"]}</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>{$var["trayecto_triun"]}</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>{$var["seccion_triun"]}</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>{$var["condicion_triun"]}</td>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href='../controlador/anadir-triunfador-controlador.php'><input type='text' class='btn btn-success' value='Añadir'></a>

          <a href='../controlador/actualizar-triunfador-controlador.php'><input  type='text' class='btn btn-primary' value='Actualizar'></a>

          <a href='../controlador/buscar-triunfador-controlador.php'><input  type='text' class='btn btn-info' value='Buscar'></a>

          <a href='../controlador/eliminar-triunfador-controlador.php?<?php echo'id=1'; ?><input  type='text' class='btn btn-danger' value='Eliminar'></a>
          </td>";
           echo "</tr>";
}
```

`
Recuerde en el modelo van todas nuestras ideas, en el controlador se crean, se materializan esas ideas y en la vista mostramos dicha creación al mundo :D espero que mi respuesta le haya servido de ayuda.

> El código ya ha sido previamente implementado por mi persona en un Sistema, de igual manera disculpa si ocurre algún error.

Comment: Buenas hermano, estoy siguiendo tu ejemplo y me surgen un par de errores y otras interrogantes, el error principalmente creo que es por que no conecto bien con la `BBDD`, en `EntidadBase` como hago para poder visualizar el resultado del `if` que me prueba la `conexion`, estoy tratando asi: `$con = new EntidadBase` - `echo $con->getStatusConexion()`, pero no me funciona, ¿Como haria?, ya que tengo poca experiencia con `poo`

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate en el constructor de la clase `Usuario`, tiene esta cabecera:

```
 public function __construct($table){
        $table = "usuarios";
        parent::__construct($table);

    }
```

Espera como parámetri el valor de la tabla, pero cuando la instancias en `UsuariosController`no le estás proporcionando ningún valor, es más ese valor ya esta definido dentro del constructor de la clase usuario.

lo instancias así:

`$usuario = new Usuario();`

Prueba cambiando el constructor de la clase `Usuario` de esta forma:

```
    public function __construct(){

        $table = "usuarios";
        parent::__construct($table);

    }
```

Comment: me aparece el siguiente error `Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in C:\wamp64\www\Php - POO\mvc\model\Usuario.php on line 14`

Comment: Entonces hay que revisar la clase conexión fíjate que tenga el mismo aspecto que esta: https://victorroblesweb.es/2014/07/15/ejemplo-php-poo-mvc/

Comment: El error se encuentra en el archivo `EntidadBase`, porque descargue el codigo del ejemplo que sigo desde `github` y si cambio mi archivo por el de el, si funciona, pero no encuentro el error, en el documento, porque revisando los 2 codigos estan iguales pero el mio no funciona y el de el si

Comment: Listo ya encontre el error en el `construct` tenia escrito `contruct` y ese era el inconveniente

Comment: Caso resuelto ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo disculpa la demora de respuesta, acabo de llegar de la universidad, bueno mi brother ahora sí, con gusto despejamos dudas, para comprobar el estado de la conexión en nuestra estructura condicional podemos hacer lo siguiente:

1- Crearemos un nuevo método o función llamada por ejemplo 'conexionActual' y dentro de ella colocarás el condicional (lo quitas del constructor y lo colocas dentro del nuevo método creado).

2- En tu modelo cambia dentro del **if** y **else** la palabra reservada **return** por **echo** , en el modelo es buena práctica utilizar **return** y más que estamos utilizando MVC para nosotros debería ser obligatorio, tómalo como costumbre hermanazo, pero para efecto de prueba colocaremos un **echo** solo para esta prueba :D tu nuevo método dentro de tu clase **EntidadBase** quedaría así:

```
public function conexionActual()
{
    if(Conexion::getStatusConexion() == true){//Verificamos el estado de la conexion
        echo "Conexion Establecida.";
    }else{
        echo "Conexion Fallida.";
    }
}
```

Y al final afuera de tu clase instancias normalmente, luego imprimiremos nuestra cadena de caracteres "Conexion Establecida." o "Conexion Fallida." todo depende si se realizó o no la conexión, sería algo así:

```
$con = new EntidadBase(); //Instanciamos normalmente
print_r($con->conexionActual()); //El objeto "$con" utiliza el metodo "conexionActual" y esto lo que hace es imprimirnos el mensaje de acuerdo a lo que haya sucedido en nuestro condicional (si se estableció la conexión o no)
```

Y así comprobaríamos mi hermano :D pienso que es oportuno mencionarle que en nuestro archivo **'conexion.php'** tenemos un método llamado **getStatusConexion** y dentro de este método tenemos una variable llamada **$this->respuestaConexion;** si revisamos bien nos daremos cuenta que la inicializamos en **false** y en nuestro **try** si la conexión se realiza correctamente el valor de esta variable cambiará a **true** si la conexión falla dentro de nuestro **catch** se encuentra la misma variable pero su valor **false** se mantiene, cuando nosotros en nuestra clase **EntidadBase** utilizamos el método **Conexion::getStatusConexion()** en el **if** nosotros lo que estamos diciendo es que si la variable dentro de ese método es igual a **true** osea que si la conexión fue exitosa pues nos imprima un mensaje "Conexion Establecida.", en caso contrario que nos imprima un mensaje diferente "Conexion Fallida." luego después de instanciar utilizamos el nuevo método creado llamado **conexionActual** y a través de el los mensajes saldrán a la luz del mundo exterior y podremos verlos :D esta es la corrida en frio de esa porción de código mi brother, espero haberte disipado la duda que tenías, suerte y siempre adelante.

> En dado caso de haber instanciado en el controlador borra esa instancia y solo has lo que te mencioné en el modelo brother ;)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta hermano, ya tengo mas claro lo que tengo que hacer, una ultima duda, ya arreglando el codigo me aparece el siguiente error `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''usuarios' ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1'`, por lo que entendi es un error de sintaxis en la consulta pero al correrla en `phpmyadmin` funciona correctamente, nose si sera porque me salto alguna regla del `PDO`

Comment: Hola hermano siempre a su orden, después de buscar un poco por San Google el error que presentas (ya que a mi no me había pasado) logré dar con una posible solución, revise su archivo en el cual está la conexión con la base de datos, siendo más explícitos dentro del **try** observará que en dado caso que el código aparezca así:  parent::__construct("pgsql  debe cambiar **pgsql** por **mysql** ya que la sentencia SQL que usted realiza y que da error pertenece  al gestor de base de datos MYSQL mi brother, y el código que le pasé está orientado a PostgreSQL :D avíseme si le funcionó, suerte bro.

Comment: Ese no es el error porque yo la principio me di cuenta de que era una conexion con `postgresql` y la modifique a `mysql`

Comment: Entiendo brother, seguiré buscando entonces y si encuentro algo de utilidad con gusto te lo haré saber :D

Comment: puede ser o no que al principio me aparecia otro error que era `Missing argument 1 for EntidadBase::__construct(), called`, el cual pude solucionar dandole un valor directo a la variable que paso al `construct`, asi `__construct($table = 'usuarios')`, no se si talvez eso influya directamente en el otro error, ademas que del ejemplo que sigo no se le declara un valor de esta forma al `$table` en el `construct`

Comment: No está de más probar brother, haz esto a ver si funciona: en tu constructor colocarás como parámetro una variable llamada **$param** _construct($param)  y dentro dentro del cuerpo del constructor puedes colocar lo siguiente: **$table = $param;** es decir, que tu tabla será igual a lo que le pases por parámetro a tu constructor, si instancias y colocas "usuario" la variable **$param** recibirá esa cadena de texto y esto se convertirá en el valor de tu variable **$table**

Comment: Ya pude resolver el problema anterior, era en la consulta `sql` estaba usando la palabra reservada `:table` solo habia que poner `` y listo, pero ahora me sale `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'prueba.'usuarios'' ` y segun lo que lei en la documentacion es que no existe la tabla, pero ese es el nombre de la tabla